# Difference between Groovy def and Java Object?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to figure out the difference between

Groovy:

```
def name = "stephanie"
```

Java:

```
Object name = "stephanie"
```

as both seem to act as objects in that to interact with them i have to cast them to their original intended type.

I was originally on a search for a java equivalent of C#'s dynamic class ( [Java equivalent to C# dynamic class type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935832/java-equivalent-to-c-dynamic-class-type) ) and it was suggested to look at Groovy's `def`

for example my impression of groovy's def is that I could do the following:

```
def DOB = new Date(1998,5,23);
int x = DOB.getYear();
```

however this wont build

thanks,steph

Solution edit:
Turns out the mistake iw as making is I had a groovy class wtih public properties (in my example above DOB) defined with def but then was attemping to access them from a .java class(in my example above calling .getYear() on it). Its a rookie mistake but the problem is once the object leaves a Groovy file it is simply treated as a Object. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: When you say `this wont build`, do you have an exception?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per se, there is not much difference between those two statements; but since Groovy is a dynamic language, you can write

```
def name = "Stephanie"
println name.toUpperCase() // no cast required
```

while you would need an explicit cast in the Java version

```
Object name = "Stephanie";
System.out.println(((String) name).toUpperCase());
```

For that reason, `def` makes much more sense in Groovy than unfounded use of `Object` in Java.

Comment: my original hope was that def performaed that way but when I tried something such as:  'def DOB = new Date(1999,5,2);     dob.getYear();'   it wont let me build

Comment: I just tried your example of .toUppercase and that also wont allow me to build.. am I missing a compiler setting or something? I'm using netbeans 6.9.1

Comment: Have you created your project as a groovy project?!?

Comment: And of course, to build something, you have to declare a class, just like in Java. It's just that the groovy console lets you enter and execute statements directly, but that's not a build.

Answer (score 4):

You can experiment with groovy in the groovy web console http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Your initial groovy date example works.