# Method arguments with and without def keyword

Tags: grails, groovy

Suppose we have the following method:

```
def myMethodWithParameters(param1, def param2, Object param3) {
    ...
}
```

**What are the differences between using the def keyword and using Object as type *for an argument*?**

**What are the differences between using the def keyword and not using any type/keyword *for an argument*?**

---

What I know so far and does not completely answer the question:

- `def` keyword is used to allow dynamic types.
  So you can even put an `Object[]` in it.
- `def` keyword can be used to make variables available only in current scope instead of globally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937271/difference-between-groovy-def-and-java-object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825109/groovy-def-keyword-vs-concrete-type

Comment: And this is the good stuff: http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_def_and_type

Comment: What bits are you missing?  The second bit?

Comment: @tim_yates Your last link did it! Provide it as a complete answer to earn carma! :)

Comment: Done :-)  Thanks!  Glad I helped :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick [link to the docs](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_def_and_type) which do a good job of explaining this:

> When defining a method with untyped parameters, you can use def but
>   it’s not needed, so we tend to omit them. So instead of:
>
> ```
> void doSomething(def param1, def param2) { }
> ```
>
> Prefer:
>
> ```
> void doSomething(param1, param2) { }
> ```
>
> But as we mention in the last
>   section of the document, it’s usually better to type your method
>   parameters, so as to help with documenting your code, and also help
>   IDEs for code-completion, or for leveraging the static type checking
>   or static compilation capabilities of Groovy.

The general rule I follow with Groovy, is:

If you know what type you expect, or return, then put that type in the definition.  If you only accept `String`, add the type to the parameter (the same with returning a value).  This goes doubly for methods which form part of your "public" API (ie: if other classes or people are going to be making use of the method).

If it's just internal, or accepts a range of value types, then leave the argument untyped, and let Groovy sort it out...