# How to make a method call to superclass of object guaranteed to have the method?

Tags: java

I have an API that processes a set of objects all extending a particular class which does not have an income field

```
class Person { ... }
```

Say I want to make a call getting incomes. Not all of the subclasses here have an income field

```
class Child { ... }
class FullTimeEmployedPerson { ... }
class TrustFundKid { ... }
```

This process would call a `#getIncome()` method on either of the latter two. Now, my API is guaranteed never to get a `Child` passed to it so I want to skip the pleasantries and simply have something like

```
String getParsedIncome(Person person) { 
    return FooBar.parse(person.getIncome());
}
```

What is a realistic approach for this?

Comment: Can you change the classes or not? It sounds like you can but it also sounds like it's from a 3rd party library (so you can't change them). Please [edit] your question to include all classes extending from `Person`.

Comment: What kind of API are you talking about? (I take it you mean REST + json) You can define an interface with a [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) `Optional<T> getIncome()`. Your classes are all implementing the interface, but only `FullTimeEmployedPerson`and `TrustFundKid` are actually returning non-empty objects.

Comment: Person class is a hypothetical example here, I cannot realistically include all subclasses from some decades old legacy application and it would not help the question more. I do not get to touch the classes involved, my API maps them to different objects depending on specs (which change way too often)

Comment: @VictorS But the mapped classes are under your control? So you can add/change classes and interfaces as you like?

Comment: Nope. Unless I create a facade class that would map to each end of the business logic separately

Comment: @VictorS It is a little bit unclear what you are asking for or what the problem is. Please [edit] your question to make it more clear what classes you get from the 3rd party library and how you want/plan to consume them in your application. Also explain how changes in the external API/classes will affect you. And describe how you will call a method like `getIncome()` when this method is not present in the base class you are using. This *might* sound like a "XY problem", but not quite yet...

Comment: @Progman I added the tidbit about it being useful in real life so that I would not get swarmed by suggestions to just implement everything completely differently. The oddly invasive details you are requesting are not relevant to the question and I am not going to include those details. If you'd prefer consider that last paragraph does not exist.

Comment: @VictorS Is it an option to use `getClass()` or `instanceof` to check if an object is a specific subclass object and cast the given object to that specific subclass object, where the method exist you want to call?

Comment: That is mainly what I want to avoid. My goal is to have the call agnostic to which specific subclass it is, except that it is a subclass of ```Person```

Comment: @VictorS What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935832/java-equivalent-to-c-sharp-dynamic-class-type? This simulates the `dynamic` keyword from C#.

Answer (score 2):

Define `getIncome()` in `Person`, throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`. Override this in subclasses where it *is* supported to return the income.

You say that it is guaranteed that only supported fields will be accessed. This approach abandons compile-time checks to ensure that is true. An alternative would be to create an interface, `IncomeHolder`, and implement it only in subclasses of `Person` that actually have an income. Then the compiler can guarantee there is no invalid usage.

Comment: This would be ideal if I had a way to change the 3rd party implementation

Answer (score 0):

You have to use reflection to check if your instance class has such method.

```
If(YourChildInstance.class.getMethod("methodName") != null){ ... }else{ do nothing}
```

I'm not 100% sure that it works. Test it and let me know if it does

Comment: unfortunately reflections are not a solution with high TPS requirements due to how expensive they are. also they do not help with maintainability either